# I was hired as a junior front-end developer and laid off after 2 months for lack of experience

Tags: work-experience, startup, developer, junior

I was interviewed by a startup founder for work as a front-end developer (ReactJs and firebase as backend), I was doing exactly what they would ask me to achieve on a weekly basis, I was paid 5€/hour and even though it may seem so little, my goal was to gain experience in front-end development and grow as an individual. This was my second job.

This week the founder asked to do video call and told me that he finds the project will grow to be more complex and will demand more skills in front-end development than the skills I have. So they will look for a senior developer, that it has nothing to do with me personally because I was always open for feedback and learning every time they would ask me to.

The reason I am asking about this: do you think I should have refused the offer because I was aware that I’m a junior and that things may get too advanced for my level or that it’s something they do in freelance to hire a junior and then move to senior as things level up?

Comment: If you want to avoid this in future, it's crucial to understand what happened _before_ you started working there. To me it sounds like there was nothing you could have done in the job, because the main reason for firing you was that they had no idea what skills they need. So, could you add more details about the hiring process and precise your intended goal?

Comment: Please keep doing more of these. The more you stretch and learn, the more likely that you will become the senior developer. I see this as simply as they tried to do it on the cheap and can't. They thought they could do it with a junior and found out that they couldn't. If they can keep you on and you can find out what the senior developer is doing, that would be great.

Comment: @Chris I definitely learned my lesson about asking questions to the recruiter. They did a video call with me, asked me about what projects I've done in the past, I had shared with the founder my github account. I was really honest with them about what I knew when it comes to front-end development.

Comment: @DavidR I will not stop learning front-end development, it's something I enjoy doing! They told me in case they would need a second developer they would reach out to me again but I know this won't happen. I will ask a friend of mine who still works there. Thank you for your support.

Comment: What's wrong with this question (why the downvotes) ?

Comment: Hahaha I have no idea why they downvoated!

Comment: Is 5€/hour even a legal wage in your locale? Did you have an actual/official contract?

Comment: 5 euro per hour is more than what I make in my country unfortunately. No there was no contract since I was still being tested. They told me that after I finish some part of the project I will get an offer. @thieupepijn

Comment: "there was no contract since I was still being tested". That's bullshit. Never work without a contract. They could let you work for weeks/months for free, and then claim "hey, you aren't what we need, so thank you, bye.". Oh.. wait. That's what happened here... I would say you have been scammed.

Comment: @jwsc Thank you for letting me know about this, I thought contract were only possible when I'd have a position on the team. Can you send me a template for contracts? Or maybe what it should cover?

Comment: You are motivated and seem like a good worker. That is definitely worth more than 5€/h even in a dirt poor country. As long as it's not anything where quality is super important, (like security) a junior dev should be able to do everything a senior can, just slower. Keep that in mind when you are talking to a possible future employer.

Comment: @geekys "Contract" is a short term for "Let's write our agreement down, to make sure we are on the same page". You don't need huge multiple page contracts like the big corporations have, but you need something in writing which covers what the framework for your working relationship is: How many hours per week, which salary, contract or salaried, probation period, payment date...

Comment: @WestCoastProjects - The question is unclear hence the reason I issued a downvote.  The title indicates the author was laid off, yet the question body makes no mention of this, other than the fact they were NOT offered the senior position.  Which isn't shocking since they were hired at the junior level.

Comment: @Jesper I actually even reduced the total amount of work hours, because I had once spent 22h to deliver a first version and they made a comment on that (it was considered too long). Thank you very much for your time and help, I learned so much from everyone who answered me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The reason I am asking about this: do you think I should have refused the offer because I was aware that I’m a junior and that things may get too advanced for my level or that it’s something they do in freelance to hire a junior and then move to senior as things level up?

As long as you make it clear to them what your skills and experience are (and conversely, the limits of your experience), then you shouldn't refuse a job offer if they make you one.

From your CV and interview process, they should have a good idea of your technical abilities (assuming that you don't overestimate your own abilities, you're honest with them, and they're competent at interviewing). If you don't have enough skills or experience for what they need, then they should not make you a job offer.

It sounds like there are a few possibilities of what happened here:

- You overestimated your own abilities, so unintentionally gave a misleading impression of them in your interview (and they failed to validate this).
- You intentionally oversold your abilities to them (and they failed to validate this).
- They overestimated their abilities or underestimated the complexity of the project.
- Their requirements changed.

As long as you're happy that you're presenting an accurate and realistic assessment of your skills and experience to them, then you've done nothing wrong. Sometimes requirements change at short notice (especially in startups). Sometimes people are bad at hiring, or underestimate how complicated things can be.

It sucks, but that's just life sometimes. Hopefully you'll have better luck with your next role (whatever it is).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I sent the founder my github account so he can see what I can achieve as a front-end developer and was really honest about what I am capable of, I tend to be someone who underestimates their skills because I believe I should constantly be improving

Comment: In which case it sounds like you did everything that you could. Sometimes jobs just don't work out - so don't beat yourself up over it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support 

Answer (score 2):

Were you happy with the salary (I don't know your country and your age)? Did you learn things? If you answer "yes" to both questions, then you're fine personally.

You were absolutely correct to accept the job. It seems nobody said you were not worth your money, just that they think they need someone more experienced.

It's not how things *usually* happen. Normally one would hire junior developers to help an experienced developer. There is work that a junior developer can do, and you'd rather let them do it (cheap) than let the experienced developer do it (expensive). Here it seems that the startup was inexperienced and didn't realise that you need at least one experienced developer. You can't develop a product with *only* junior developers (unless you get someone by luck who is extraordinarily smart).

Comment: I live in north Africa, thank you for answering my question 